# Get Size of Text/Font in a PDF File using PDFBox from Apache

Tags: java, pdfbox

the task is to write a Java file that analyzes a PDF file. PDFBox from Apache should be used.
The number of words, the number of images, the names of the fonts used, etc. are all no problem.

My problem is: How do I get all used Font Sizes in the PDF file? I read a lot, that I have to use TextStrippe and writeString, but I dont see a solution.
So how do I get the Font Sizes in pt. for a pdf file? Has anyone an idea or solution?

Comment: You can use the "xscale" output of the `PrintTextLocations.java` example.

Comment: Alternatively consider using the `TextPosition.getYScale()` - if that value and the `TextPosition.getXScale()` differ, more often the Y scale is the expected value.

Comment: Ok it is the YScale. But how can I get the value? The PrintTextLocations.java only print on the comment line. There is no return value?

Comment: Update: Worked. Thank you!